# String formatted date as X axis in stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, stacked-area-chart

I am referring below code to create stacked area chart.
HTML:

```
<style>

#chart svg {
  height: 400px;
}

</style>
<div id="chart">
  <svg></svg>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
                .x(function(d) { return d[0] })
                .y(function(d) { return d[1] })
                .clipEdge(true)
                .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
                ;

  chart.xAxis
      .showMaxMin(false)
      .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) });

  chart.yAxis
      .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));

  d3.select('#chart svg')
    .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

JSON Data

```
[ 
        { 
          "key" : "Test" , 
          "values" : [
            [ 1025409600000 , 23.041422681023] , 
            [ 1028088000000 , 19.854291255832] 
            ]
        },
  ]
```

But I want to put date in string format and not in millisecond.

```
[ 
        { 
          "key" : "Test" , 
          "values" : [
            [ "2016-11-25", 23.041422681023] , 
            [ "2016-11-26", 19.854291255832] 
            ]
        },
]
```

How can I provide this json format as an input to area graph. If I apply it as its javascript throws invalid number error. Any help ?

Comment: use var s = new Date(1025409600000) to get date and then do s.getFullYear() + "-" + (s.getMonth()+1) + "-" + s.getDate()

Comment: I don't have date in milliseconds. I am fetching data using ajax and response gives me only date in String format like "2016-11-25"

Comment: are you asking to convert string to milliseconds ?

Comment: No... Can I pass date in string format as it is  to area chart  without converting it to milliseconds ?

Comment: Yes you can because anyway this is going to be convert to date object at .tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d)) }); in both the case millisecond or yyyy-mm-dd will yield same result for date not for time because millisecond has all time details but not yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Yes.. but using same code for string date errors occurs that "Not a number  MNAN" as function expects number. So do I need to change tickFormat function ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the solutions you can use to solve your problem

1. Convert the array from date string to milliseconds before passing to chart
2. Pass data as it is but write a parsing function for x axes values

   var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
           .x(function(d) { return ( (new Date(d[0])).getTime()) })

Note : `chart.xAxis.tickFormat()` is for generating label based on values which is used to draw the chart.

Answer (score 0):

Try this! I know this question is way old to answer now but hope this can help somebody in the future.

```
var chart = nv.models.stackedAreaChart()
              .x(function(d) { return Number(new Date(d[0])) })
```